# SQL: "NOT IN" subquery optimization or alternatives

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have two database tables: "places" and "translations". The translations of places names are made by selecting records from "places", which don't have the translations to the specified language yet:

```
SELECT `id`, `name`
FROM `places`
WHERE `id` NOT IN (SELECT `place_id` FROM `translations` WHERE `lang` = 'en')
```

This worked fine with 7 000 records of places, but crashed when the number of translations reached 5 000. Since then, the query takes about 10 seconds and returns the error:

> ## 2006 - MySQL server has gone away

As I understand, the main problem here is the subquery returning to many results, bu how could I solve it, if I need to select all the places which are not translated yet?

My plan B is to create a new boolean field in "places" table, called "translated", and reset it to "false", each time I change language - that would prevent for having subquery. However, maybe I could just modify my current SQL statement and prevent from adding additional field?

Comment: Not an answer, more of suggestion if it's still possible at your project's stage.  When I have those incessant "MySQL Server has gone away" errors popping up, I ported my app to Postgresql.  Never looked back since

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The obvious alternative:

```
SELECT
  `id`, `name`
FROM
  `places`
WHERE 
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM `translations` WHERE `id` = `places`.`id` AND `lang` = 'en'
  )
```

There should be a clustered composite index over `(translations.id, translations.lang)` (composite means: a single index over multiple fields, clustered means: the index governs how the table is sorted).

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was missing.

Comment: @Kernius: Can you post what difference that change makes for you in comparison? (the index is important!)

Comment: I had indexed those fields before and still was having that problem, which simply disapeared, when I switched to yours suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I believe that the best alternative is to do 2 separate queries. Storing the result of the first in a variable and using the second.